# Elimination Method - 3 Variables

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

$$-2x + y + 2z  = 0$$
$$2x - 2y - 2z = 0$$
$$3x + y  - 3z = 0$$

I got $y = 0$ and $x = z$ but I can't go any further. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You're done.  Every triple of the form $\{x,y,z\}=\{x,0,x\}$ works and every solution has that form.

Comment: @JackieAo: Look up "Free Variables".

Comment: Indeed, this is an example of an underdetermined system.

Answer (score 1):

Your system has infinitly many  solutions since there are fewer leading ones than unknown variables if converted to an augmented matrix.

So let $z =t $ for some $t \in \mathbb{R} \Rightarrow x = t $.

So your final solution is $x=t , y=2, z=t, $ $\forall t  \in \mathbb{R}$.

Answer (score 0):

You've found the solution. Substite x for z and 0 for y to see for yourself.

-2x + (0) + 2(x) = 0

2x - 2(0) - 2(x) = 0

3x + (0) - 3(x) = 0